# I want use an Inner join function in a shiny module with column name as variable

Tags: r, shiny, inner-join

I would like execute an **inner_join** with a variable name of the dataframe column.
I ve used variables names for the column **ComposanteTableau1** and **ComposanteTableau2**, I ve an issue with the variables names whish are not replaced by their value **Indice4** and **Indice2** ***(this is in a Shiny Server module***)

The code in the server module :

```
cat(file=stderr(), "ComposanteTableau1", ComposanteTableau1, "\n")
      cat(file=stderr(), "ComposanteTableau2", ComposanteTableau2, "\n")
      cat(file=stderr(), "debug", names(df1), "\n")
      cat(file=stderr(), "debug", names(df2), "\n")
      browser()
      total <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c(ComposanteTableau1 = ComposanteTableau2))
```

The debug with the browser() function.

> ComposanteTableau1 Indice4
>
> ComposanteTableau2 Indice2
>
> debug Indice4 Valeur1
>
> debug Indice2 Valeur
>
> Called from:
> `<observer:observeEvent(input$actBtnCroisementData)>`(...) Browse[1]>
> n
>
> debug à
> /home/guillaume/Documents/A_segment_Pro/A_segment/ProcessCrossJoin/appSauv.R#307
> :total <- **inner_join(df1, df2, by = c(ComposanteTableau1 =
> ComposanteTableau2))** Browse[2]> n
>
> Warning: Error in : Join columns must be present in data. x Problem
> with `ComposanteTableau1`.

In debug, i'm able to replace the ComposanteTableau1 and ComposanteTableau2 by "Indice4" and "Indice2" and the inner join is right, but not during the run.

Thanks in advance for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I ve found a bypass to use column name. But I was not able to use the inner_join but only the merge function like these.

**`total <- merge(df1, df2, by.x=ComposanteTableau1,by.y=ComposanteTableau2)`**

I you find the way with inner_join it could be a good news.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setNames` to use `dplyr::inner_join` with variables.

```
total <- dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2, 
                         by = setNames(ComposanteTableau2, ComposanteTableau1))
```